# Async/await fetch with Typescript using NextJS 13 App router

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, fetch-api, next.js13

I set up a fetch functionality with typescript for NextJS 13. Since I'm relatively new to Typescript, I'd like to ask if this is a correct approach and/or if I'm overlooking something.

utils.ts

```
enum HTTPMethods {
  GET = "GET",
  POST = "POST",
  PUT = "PUT",
  PATCH = "PATCH",
  DELETE = "DELETE",
}

function handleError(status: number, message: string) {
  throw new Error(`${status}: ${message}`);
}

async function request<TResponse>(
  url: string,
  config: RequestInit
): Promise<TResponse> {
  const response = await fetch(url, config);
  if (!response.ok) {
    handleError(response.status, response.statusText);
  }
  return await response.json();
}


export async function _get<TResponse>(url: string): Promise<TResponse> {
  return request<TResponse>(url, { method: HTTPMethods.GET });
}

export async function _post<TBody extends BodyInit, TResponse>(
  url: string,
  body: TBody
): Promise<TResponse> {
  return request<TResponse>(url, { method: HTTPMethods.POST, body });
}
```

page.tsx

```
//imports

const { products } = await _get<ProductsType>(
 `${process.env.CLIENT_API_URL}/products`
);

//return
```

types.d.ts

```
type ProductType = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  price: number;
  // other properties
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write several functionalities to help you send GET/POST requests, this approach is not wrong. Whether this is the best practice depends on you and your projects. You know, providing some help functionalities will help us write code faster, but it also makes some constraints.

Comment: Okay great thanks for answering! I’m particularly unsure if im doing enough error handling and if i’m doing it correctly. In the handleError function I’m throwing an Error and this results in Next rendering the error.tsx page automatically, though i’m not sure if this qualifies as ‘handling’ the error.

Comment: Yes, your way of handling errors is okay. If you want to display an error page to user when an error throws, you should do this, otherwise a default error page will be displayed in the  browser.